# Move Folder and its contents to Other Folder

Tags: c#

I am working on an asp.net application where i have to move any Folder and its contents to another. Suppose i have a Main folder and in that folder there is 3 subfolders. In each subfolder there is a file. I want to move folder and all its contents to another place. For this i used the following code

```
if (!Directory.Exists(@"E:\Sunny\C#FolderCopy"))
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(@"E:\Sunny\C#FolderCopy");
   Directory.Move(@"E:\Sunny\C#Folder\", @"E:\Sunny\C#FolderCopy\");
}
```

But when the control reaches to move function The error comes as

> Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

How to solve this

Comment: Works fine for me. Check your folder structure

Comment: But when i want to Folder named "c#Folder" to newly created Directory named "c#FolderCopy" then this error comes.

Comment: Does removing the ".CreateDirectory" call fix anything for you?

Comment: After creating the new directory i want to move Folder and its contents to that new directory

Comment: Check out romano's answer, that where i wanted to go with my question ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Directory.Move` already creates the folder for you. You only need to adjust to the following:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(@"E:\Sunny\C#FolderCopy"))
{
   Directory.Move(@"E:\Sunny\C#Folder\", @"E:\Sunny\C#FolderCopy\");
}
```

If you want to copy the folder (as indicated by your comment) you can use `FileSystem.CopyDirectory`. It is located in a Visual Basic namespace but that should be of no concern at all:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

if (!Directory.Exists(@"E:\Sunny\C#FolderCopy"))
{
   FileSystem.CopyDirectory(@"E:\Sunny\C#Folder\", @"E:\Sunny\C#FolderCopy\");
}
```

Or use this method (taken from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914(v=vs.100).aspx)):

```
DirectoryCopy(".", @".\temp", true);

private static void DirectoryCopy(
    string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
{
  DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
  DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

  // If the source directory does not exist, throw an exception.
    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
            + sourceDirName);
    }

    // If the destination directory does not exist, create it.
    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }


    // Get the file contents of the directory to copy.
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        // Create the path to the new copy of the file.
        string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);

        // Copy the file.
        file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
    }

    // If copySubDirs is true, copy the subdirectories.
    if (copySubDirs)
    {

        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            // Create the subdirectory.
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);

            // Copy the subdirectories.
            DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here source folder deleted after copy But i want to move the main folder C#Folder to destination with the main folder i.e. C#Folder.

Comment: What you want to do is copy the source folder. When you move it the original directory no longer exists (since you moved it ;-)

Comment: Here i am using c# not Visualbasic and the second code u wrote is using namespace of VisualBasic

Comment: As I stated in my answer, that is no problem. After all it is all .Net you can use the Visual Basic namespace in your C# code. Or use the third method I described

Comment: The second example u wrote is copying only contents of main folder but i want to keep the main folder also to destination

Comment: What do you mean by "but i want to keep the main folder also to destination"?

Comment: I want to copy the folder and its content like subfolders, File to destination in such a way that the main folder should also exists in the destination folder

Comment: So the old folder should be a subdirectory of the new folder?  Then use `FileSystem.CopyDirectory(@"E:\Sunny\C#Folder\", @"E:\Sunny\C#FolderCopy\C#Folder\");`

Answer (score 2):

Recursive Files Move.
Call this method and all it do.

```
public static void MoveDirectory(string source, string target)
{
    var sourcePath = source.TrimEnd('\\', ' ');
    var targetPath = target.TrimEnd('\\', ' ');
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         .GroupBy(s=> Path.GetDirectoryName(s));
    foreach (var folder in files)
    {
        var targetFolder = folder.Key.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetFolder);
        foreach (var file in folder)
        {
            var targetFile = Path.Combine(targetFolder, Path.GetFileName(file));
            if (File.Exists(targetFile)) File.Delete(targetFile);
            File.Move(file, targetFile);
        }
    }
    Directory.Delete(source, true);
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of your method in comparison to `Directory.Move`? No critique intended, just curious.

Comment: This will do a recursive move. All Sub Files and Folders will move with this method.